# How to show that the set of proper subspaces of a finite dimentinoal vector space $V$ is closed under unions of chains?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. How to show that the set of proper subspaces of $V$  is closed under unions of chains? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: show that every chain has a maximal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V = \text{span}\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n\}$, and suppose $\{W_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is a chain of proper subspaces such that
$$
V = \cup W_{\alpha}
$$
Then, each $e_i$ must be in some $W_{\alpha_i}$, and so must be in some $W_{\beta}$ where $\beta \geq \alpha_j$ for all $j$. Hence, $W_{\beta} = V$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A chain of proper subspaces of a **finite** dimensional vector space is eventually stationary, because if $W, X$ are subspaces of $V$ such that e.g. $W\subseteq X$ and $\text{dim}W=\text{dim}X$, then $W=X$. Now if $\{W_i\}$ is a chain of subspaces, then there is some subspace $W_i$ in this chain with maximal dimension and by the above every subsequent $W_j$ must equal that $W_i$.